# LIMIT on main table if join tables have where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have three table Contact, Company, Individuals. Contact can have only one company and can have multiple Individuals. I am trying to fetch Contacts along with associated data and with multiple OR clauses which contain conditions for both the associated table. Also I just want to apply limit only on Contact table.

Here is query:-

```
SELECT          "Contact"."contactType", 
                "Contact"."id", 
                "Contact"."createdAt", 
                "Contact"."updatedAt", 
                "Company"."id"            AS "Company.id", 
                "Company"."name"          AS "Company.name", 
                "Company"."compType"   AS "Company.compType", 
                "Company"."affType" AS "Company.affType", 
                "Company"."lsNo"     AS "Company.lsNo", 
                "Individuals"."id"        AS "Individuals.id", 
                "Individuals"."firstName" AS "Individuals.firstName" 
FROM            "Contacts"    AS "Contact" 
INNER JOIN      "Companies"         AS "Company" 
ON              "Contact"."id" = "Company"."ContactId" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "Individuals" AS "Individuals" 
ON              "Contact"."id" = "Individuals"."ContactId" 
WHERE           ( 
                       "Company"."affType" ilike ANY (array['abc','xyz'])
                AND    "Contact"."contactType" ilike ANY (array['def','jkl'])
                AND             ( 
                                                lower(cast("Company"."name" AS text)) LIKE '%abc%'
                                OR              lower(cast("Company"."compType" AS text)) LIKE '%as%'
                                OR              lower(cast("Company"."lsNo" AS text)) LIKE '%as%'
                                OR              lower(cast("Individuals"."firstName" AS text)) LIKE '%as%'))
ORDER BY    "Company"."name" ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

The problem with above query is that limit is getting applied on Individuals.

Comment: What do you mean "I just want to apply limit only on Contact table." Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Can you please share your sequelize statement?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use a lateral join with a subquery:

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL 
    (SELECT * from "Individuals" WHERE "Contact"."id" = "Individuals"."ContactId" LIMIT 10) as "Individuals" on true
```

Although you might want to apply some sort of ORDER BY to specify which individuals have priority to be returned.

You probably also want to move/copy `lower(cast("Individuals"."firstName" AS text)) LIKE '%as%'` from the outer WHERE clause into the subquery.

Comment: if I move "lower(cast("Individuals"."firstName" AS text)) LIKE '%as%'" to subquery  then this will become AND condition. I just want that LIMIT apply only in "Contacts" after all condition are met.

Comment: If you don't copy it into the subquery and the first 10 individuals it sees happen not to match '%as%', then the left join will kick in and generate a NULL, which then can't match that branch of the OR anyay.  It is not clear what your desired output is, but that doesn't seem likely to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subquery to limit the number of rows from the Contact table before joining it with the other tables, like:

```
SELECT          "Contact"."contactType", 

-- Other selections

FROM (SELECT * FROM Contact LIMIT 10) 

-- Remaining query (joins and filters)

ORDER BY co.name ASC;
```